# Git core.safecrlf different behavior on files with same line endings

Tags: windows, git, cygwin, newline, core.autocrlf

I have Windows machine with VS project and I use both Visual Studio and tools from Cygwin environment including Git. Sometimes I get different line endings in files after editing. I want simple solution to check files' line ending consistency before they go to the repo. Git's `core.safecrlf` is the right thing I suppose.
Now I have a strange behavior:

Files `A` and `B` with following parameters:

```
$file A
A: HTML document, UTF-8 Unicode text, with CRLF line terminators
$file B
B: HTML document, UTF-8 Unicode (with BOM) text, with CRLF line terminators
```

File A is already in repo, file B is new one. Note, both have CRLF line endings. Now try to stage them, `core.safecrlf` is `true`.

```
$git add A  # ok
$git add B  # fails
fatal: CRLF would be replaced by LF in B.
```

Am using `core.safecrlf` correctly? Or maybe I need to write hook to check files?

Notes:

- tried with different file encodings (with and without BOM), no difference.
- there's related `core.autocrlf` feature in Git, added it to tags (Stackoverflow has no tag for `core.safecrlf`)
- git version 1.8.5.rc1.17.g0ecd94d (compiled from sources under Cygwin)

EDIT #1: checked out `core.autocrlf` - it was `input`. Changed to `false`, now I can add both files. Why?

Answer (score 51, accepted):

According to your later edit `core.autocrlf = input` was the original setting. With this setting `CRLF` is converted to `LF` when checked in to the repository and **is kept that way** when checked out. This means a non Unix line endings aware editor like Notepad would mess up the appearance of a checked out version of the file. It would be one giant long line.

FWIW `core.autocrlf = input` is the preferred setting on Unix systems and using the default `cygwin` build probably set it that way. In Windows the recommended settings is `core.autocrlf = true` which is what `msysgit` recommends

`core.safecrlf = true` aborts the conversion of a file if checking out the file will result in a changed and possibly damaged file which would be the case if Notepad was the editor. This is why file B was aborted because it would be messed up in an editor like Notepad. The difference between `core.SAFEcrlf` and `core.AUTOcrlf` should be noted. It is one of the `eyes glazing over` issues in understanding `git` line endings

`core.autocrlf = false` is don't care mode. It will check in and check out the files exactly as they are, which is why the commits now work. This is not very smart and is not recommended because it causes problems if the files are edited on both Windows and Unix systems and also if another users `core.autocrlf` settings differ and change the file endings.

My own preference is to set `core.autocrlf` to `input` on Windows if **all** the Windows editors and other text file processing tools on the project are Unix line ending aware, otherwise set it to `core.autocrlf = true` for Windows and `core.autocrlf = input` for Unix. In any case this approach is outmoded by the superior method of the `.gitattributes` file.

The `.gitattributes` file method processes files based on the file name and is maintained in all users environments as it is checked out into the working directory like `.gitignore`. The settings for as many file names and types as are relevant to your project should be added to `.gitattributes`. Your configuration then falls back onto the local core.autocrlf and core.safecrlf settings if the file name is not matched in `.gitattributes`. Adding `*   text=auto` at the top of `.gitattributes` will cause `git` to do a best guess on file names which are not matched by the later `.gitattributes` settings.

This web page, [Mind the End of Your Line](http://adaptivepatchwork.com/2012/03/01/mind-the-end-of-your-line/) helped me understand the issue better. You might read for more background on the issue.

Answer (score 4):

The CR LF line ending choices are not that easy to understand. There are two places for the descriptions in that it is covered both in Git-attributes and Git-config manuals.

Initially there were the autocrlf settings, and then there were the newer versions which have some potential incompatibilities (i.e. do unexpected things as you indicate).

I tend to set the eol=LF, which makes all text files be committed as LF line endings (you can set attributes as to which files are considered text) and then add the safecrlf for doing a round trip check.

Comment: Per documentation, line endings in files treated as text are *always* committed as LF.  The `eol=` attribute simply determines what you get in the *worktree*.  As for compatibility, newer versions still interpret the old `core.autocrlf` in a sensible manner.

Comment: @Kevin it is quite possible to have repositories that have CRLF within the committed files. It's just not the recommended/default practice. It's not worth dying in a ditch for, though some have tried ;-)