# git commit get fatal error "fatal: CRLF would be replaced by LF in"

Tags: git, eol

I'm using Ubuntu 13.10 x64, and I am working on a project that some developers are using Windows , I recently changed the git config `core.eol` to "lf" and `core.autocrlf` to "input" and `core.safecrlf` to "true". Since then, when I try to commit file into my local repository, I get this error:
`fatal: CRLF would be replaced by LF in ......`
From what I understand, if I set `core.eol` to "lf" and `core.autocrlf` to "input", git will automatically convert CRLF to LF, but why this error come out? How can I fix this problem?

Thank you.

Answer (score 237, accepted):

This is a classic issue:

[image: http://toub.es/sites/toub.es/files/styles/standard_article/public/field/image/firstcommit.png]
(picture from [Luis Tubes](http://toub.es/about)'s [blog post](http://toub.es/2012/05/28/fatal-crlf-would-be-replaced-lf))

The usual fix is to convert those files yourself, with [dos2unix](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7068241/6309) or [Swiss File Knife](http://stahlworks.com/dev/index.php?tool=remcrlf).

I have always preferred to [keep `core.autocrlf` to `false`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2825829/6309), which means:

```
git config --global core.autocrlf false
```

Comment: That error message even creeps in the `git diff` output: http://git.661346.n2.nabble.com/git-diff-returns-fatal-error-with-core-safecrlf-is-set-to-true-td7590136.html

Comment: Why git can't change CRLF to LF for me if I already set `core.autocrlf` to input ?

Comment: @William because you are working on Linux, and with files coming from Windows.

Comment: Thank you, @VonC,  I already use dos2unix to change all files eol, So when the Windows developers commit some code to their repo,if I pull from their repository, git will convert CRLF to LF , right? Our git server is on Ubuntu.

Comment: @William yes (although I really don't like such "global" changes). Is it possible some files weren't changed, before you modify the config of this repo, and are now affected because you modified and want to git add them to the index?

Comment: I'm not sure what do you mean? sorry for my bad English. If I changed all files eol to LF, then commit and push, will it effect those Windows developer when they pull from my repo then try commit?Will they see same error `fatal: LF would be replaced by CRLF in ...`

Comment: @William I mean that you said "I recently changed the `git config core.eol` to "`lf`" and `core.autocrlf` to "`input`"": that doesn't change the files already there. That would have an impact on future `git pull`. The current files are still in CRLF, and if modified, are converted to LF if possible, and, if not, triggers the error message you mention.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41781/discussion-between-william-and-vonc)

Comment: Addendum: The dos2unix CLI is most easily installed via Homebrew (and not npm).

Comment: i converted the file using dos2unix, and it works great. Does anyone knows if core.autocrlf false has any bad effect for windows developers? And what about core.safecrlf false? Is it also necessary?

Comment: @AhmetCetin no, no bad effect for Windows user: `core.autocrlf false` is fine. safecrlf is safer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/21046682/6309, but I prefer using gitattributes: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10855862/6309

Comment: Doe not work for me in Windows, still get this error

Comment: @AlekseyKontsevich Strange. Can you ask a new question, with the exact version of your git and Windows?

Comment: Solved for now with git config core.safecrlf warn

Answer (score 67):

I had the same problem and tried the suggested solution with no success.

I had to execute a second command to make it work:

```
$ git config --global core.autocrlf false
$ git config --global core.safecrlf false
```

Here is the Git documentation for `core.autocrlf`:

> `core.autocrlf`
>
> Setting this variable to "true" is the same as setting the `text` attribute to "auto" on all files and core.eol to "crlf". Set to true if you want to have CRLF line endings in your working directory and the repository has LF line endings. This variable can be set to `input`, in which case no output conversion is performed.

Here is the Git documentation for `core.safecrlf`:

> `core.safecrlf`
>
> If true, makes Git check if converting CRLF is reversible when end-of-line conversion is active. Git will verify if a command modifies a file in the work tree either directly or indirectly. For example, committing a file followed by checking out the same file should yield the original file in the work tree. If this is not the case for the current setting of `core.autocrlf`, Git will reject the file. The variable can be set to "warn", in which case Git will only warn about an irreversible conversion but continue the operation.
>
> [... rest of documentation cut for brevity ...]

Comment: are there any negative ramifications to this extra edit?

Answer (score 30):

```
$ git config core.autocrlf false
```

Comment: I don't know what this does but it works. The fatal warning goes away and I'm no longer scared.

Comment: I did this and now `git diff` sees my entire file (1000 lines) as a conflict. The diff tools only see 3 line changes.

Answer (score 16):

One may just try `dos2unix` ([man page](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/noble/en/man1/dos2unix.1.html)):

```
dos2unix [filename]
```

This converts all the CRLF line breaks in a file to LF line breaks.

Answer (score 6):

This happened to me on thousands of files. So I wrote a quick bash script to make `dos2unix` fix it for me. Someone else on Linux or Mac might find it useful.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

unwindows() {

  local errmsg
  local fpath

  # base case
  errmsg="$(git add . 2>&1)"
  if [[ $? -eq 0 ]]; then
    echo 'Successfully converted CRLF to LF in all files.'
    echo 'Successfully ran "git add .".'
    echo 'Done.'
    return 0
  fi

  fpath="${errmsg#*fatal: CRLF would be replaced by LF in }"
  fpath="${fpath%.*}"

  if [[ "${fpath}" == "${errmsg}" ]]; then
    err 'Regex failed. Could not auto-generate filename from stderr.'
    return 1
  fi

  if [[ ! -e "${fpath}" ]]; then
    err "Regex failed. '${fpath}' does not exist."
    return 1
  fi

  if ! dos2unix "${fpath}"; then
    err "Failed to run \"dos2unix '${fpath}'\"."
    return 1
  fi

  # recursive case
  unwindows
}

err() {
  local -r msg="$1"
  echo "${msg}" >&2
}

unwindows
```

Basically, it tries to do `git add .`. If the command fails, it grabs the name of the incompatible file from the error output. Then it runs `dos2unix` on that file. It keeps repeating this process until `git add .` works.

If you run this, you should see `dos2unix: converting file xxx to Unix format...` repeatedly. If you don't, it's not working, so just press <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd> or <kbd>command</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd> to stop it.

Comment: In case anyone's curious how I managed to rack up thousands of uncommitted files, it's because the repo has a bunch of code-generated images. I wasn't postponing a commit for 3 years or anything.

Answer (score 2):

FYI not sure if this applies to you but I was getting this error when accidentally trying to add all `node_modules` to the staged changes. So actually `.gitignoring` the `node_modules` solved my problem.

Answer (score 1):

I faced same trouble and fixed with editing `.gitattributes` as below.

```
$ vim .gitattributes
```

**comment out 2 lines in .gitattributes**

```
-* text=auto
-* text eol=lf
+# * text=auto
+# * text eol=lf
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm on a Mac using Terminal and had this problem with an .htaccess file I was trying to commit, getting the fatal error:

```
fatal: CRLF would be replaced by LF in .htaccess
```

I wanted to fix the problem, like the OP requests, not just turn off a git flag, so I found [this article](https://ksaitor.com/2017-11-14/fatal-crlf-would-be-replaced-by-lf/) that gives a perl command to fix the problem on a per file basis.

```
perl -pi -e 's/\r\n/\n/g' input.file
```

So for my .htaccess error above, I ran the following:

```
perl -pi -e 's/\r\n/\n/g' .htaccess
```

The flags -p, -i and -e (pie) can be combined to allow you to edit files using Perl from the command line. In this case replacing all \r\n found with \n.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add all files that `git status` displays as modified:

```
git add file1
git add file2
```

And then commit your changes :

```
git commit
```

This will keep your local files as is, but will `autocrlf` them on the remote repository.

Comment: This doesn't work. The fatal error still displays.