# I changed my line endings settings in Git. I still can't stage files due to line endings in SourceTree

Tags: git, macos, atlassian-sourcetree

I used this global setting:

```
$ git config --global core.autocrlf input
```

Which should leave line endings in LF on my OSX system. I then try to stage files in sourcetree but receive but receive this fatal error:

> fatal: CRLF would be replaced by LF in...

To my understanding, I want to convert CRLF to LF on my OSX system, correct? Is that git cmd above incorrect for that? Why do I receive this fatal error in SourceTree? Also, I hate git.

Answer (score 1):

This solved my problem (likely in addition to the post from Benjamin Close). Don't know why.

```
$ git config --global core.autocrlf false
$ git config --global core.safecrlf false
```

[git commit get fatal error "fatal: CRLF would be replaced by LF in"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20168639/git-commit-get-fatal-error-fatal-crlf-would-be-replaced-by-lf-in/31144141#31144141)

Answer (score 0):

There's instructions [here](https://help.github.com/articles/dealing-with-line-endings/#platform-mac), that provide you with details about how to fix the problem. You need to reset your index and commit fixed files before continuing now you've made the change.

Comment: I trust this advice may be as good as it gets but it has not resolved my problem.