# Android Studio "fatal: CRLF would be replaced by LF”

Tags: git, android-studio

I enabled Android Studio version control by clicking `VCS` -> `Enable version control`. Then it shows all my files are unversioned at this stage. So I right click on my project and `Git` -> `Add`, but then it gives me `Error Adding Files`

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [git commit get fatal error "fatal: CRLF would be replaced by LF in"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20168639/git-commit-get-fatal-error-fatal-crlf-would-be-replaced-by-lf-in)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+fatal%3A+CRLF+would+be+replaced+by+LF

Answer (score 0):

Here is a little trick that unexpectedly solved my problem. Instead of adding the entire project, I added one file first (any file), by clicking on the file, then `VCS` -> `Git` -> `Add`. Then I selected app, and I was able to add the entire project.